# How to consume .net asmx web services in php

Tags: php, .net, web-services, soap, asmx

web service url : http://www.domain.com/WebService1.asmx?wsdl

```
Method name : Login
params (username,password)
```

web service developed in .NET
I am call this web service with soap library.
The data will be return in json format.

i am getting an error their is **no xml document** , while call this webservice in php
the error is :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] looks like we got no XML document
```

Comment: It looks like PHP is expecting a SOAP response, not JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the form other domain 
Use Jsonp
The Example is below

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  data: 'id=10',
  jsonp: 'jsonp_callback',
  url: 'http://myotherserver.com/getdata',
  success: function () {
    // do stuff
  },
});
```

Hope This will help